# How to skip Key and value from array inside foreach?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have struggle in set start point in PHP array

PHP CODE

```
for($k=0; $k<count($AddClmn); $k++){
            $ord = 0;
            foreach($AddClmn[$k] as $ky=>$vl){
                $clmns[] = array('head'=>$ky, 'src'=>$vl, 'typ'=>'datatyp', 'NEMERIC'=>'', 'wdth'=>'70', 'ord'=>$ord);
                $ord++;
            }
        }
file_put_contents('Tracing.txt', print_r($clmns, true));
```

My actual output is above PHP code

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [head] => locid
        [src] => 1
        [typ] => datatyp
        [NEMERIC] => 
        [wdth] => 70
        [ord] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [head] => hhs
        [src] => 2525252
        [typ] => datatyp
        [NEMERIC] => 
        [wdth] => 70
        [ord] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [head] => LA0
        [src] => 9831808.388559164
        [typ] => datatyp
        [NEMERIC] => 
        [wdth] => 70
        [ord] => 2
    )
)
```

in above result i want skip first two array and i want 3 rd array as start with index 0. how to set pointer or any way to face this situation? i except result is

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [head] => LA0
        [src] => 9831808.388559164
        [typ] => datatyp
        [NEMERIC] => 
        [wdth] => 70
        [ord] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [head] => LA1
        [src] => 12920638.804462105
        [typ] => datatyp
        [NEMERIC] => 
        [wdth] => 70
        [ord] => 3
    )
```

how to solve this prob ?

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [locid] => 1
            [hhs] => 2525252
            [LA0] => 9831808.388559164
            [LA1] => 12920638.804462105
            [LA2] => 6345274.235857028
            [LA3] => 2600257.9218634316
            [LA4] => 1136632.8957946603
            [LA5] => 537362.7534893887
            [LA6] => 771599.00
            [LA7] => 941243.00
            [LA8] => 370525.00
            [LA9] => 217441.00
            [LA10] => 59977.00
            [LA11] => 19811.00
        ))`  This is actually my $AddClmn array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this -

```
foreach($AddClmn[$k] as $ky=>$vl){
  if(substr( $ky, 0, 2 ) === "LA") {
    //your code
  }
} // end for loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($k=2; $k<count($AddClmn); $k++){
            $ord = 0;
            foreach($AddClmn[$k] as $ky=>$vl){
                $clmns[] = array('head'=>$ky, 'src'=>$vl, 'typ'=>'datatyp', 'NEMERIC'=>'', 'wdth'=>'70', 'ord'=>$ord);
                $ord++;
            }
        }
file_put_contents('Tracing.txt', print_r($clmns, true));
```

Use this code..

Answer (score 1):

//you have an array like that

```
$data = array(
    '0' => 'Hello',   //you want to skip this

    '1' => 'Hello1', //you want to skip this

    '2' => 'Hello2',
    );   

 $skipped = array('0', '1');

    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        if(in_array($key, $skipped)){
            continue;
        }
        //do your stuf
    }
```

Comment: in your example set numeric index but in my array contain string as index like `'locid'=>15565`

Comment: As like as same  $skipped = array('locid');

Comment: if you have array in array you can use this as $skipped = array(array('0', '1'));

Answer (score 1):

// The following lines will remove values from the first two indexes.

```
    unset($array[0]);
    unset($array[1]);
```

// This line will re-set the indexes (new array will set from '0' index)

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

// The following line will show the new content of the array

```
 print_r($array);
```

Comment: I have used unset() but 3rd index is 2 but i want 3rd index as 0 after unset();

Answer (score 0):

With **PHP >= 5.3** Use this function to flatten (aka remove one "layer") your array by one level:

```
function flatten(array $array) {
    $return = array();
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] =     $a; });
    return $return;
}
```